# How to truncate text obtained from a MySQL database and append ellipses?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to truncate text that have been obtained via `mysql_fetch_array`, but for some reason the `strlen` cannot be calculated properly. My code is as follows:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $text = $row['text'];
        $moretext = $row['moretext'];
            if (strlen($text) > 210 || strlen($moretext) > 210) {
               $text = substr($text, 0, 210)."...";
               $moretext = substr($moretext, 0, 210)."...";
             }
    }
```

How do I get this to work so that it calculates the length of the text and appends an ellipses if it exceeds the specified amount, in this case 210 characters.

Comment: What result are you getting that makes you believe the strlen cannot be calculated properly? Also, what format are the 'text' and 'moretext' columns of the mysql table?

Comment: @GabrielRoth it is just plain UTF8 text. I'm not sure if the `strlen` is being calculated properly as it adds ellipses even when the text is under the specified amount. The biggest issue is that it automatically adds ellipses if there are just 20 characters but the text contains a question mark.

Comment: Have you seen php's multi-byte strlen function [mb_strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Noting that you're testing against the length of $text OR the length of $moretext, if **either** of those has a length greater than 210, ellipses are going to be appended to **both**.  Assuming that's not the desired behavior, you need to separate this into two if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$text = $row['text'];
$moretext = $row['moretext'];

$text = strlen($text) <= 210 ? $text : substr($text, 0, 210) . "...";
$moretext = strlen($moretext) <= 210 ? $moretext : substr($moretext, 0, 210) . "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should let MySQL do the the truncation for you

You can use [MySQL's IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
select
    IF(LENGTH(moretext) > 210,CONCAT(LEFT(moretext,210),'...'),moretext) moretext
from mip where active = 1;
```

or

```
select
    IF(LENGTH(moretext) > 210,CONCAT(SUBSTR(moretext,1,210),'...'),moretext) moretext
from mip where active = 1;
```

That way, when you execute `mysql_fetch_array`, the field is already setup for you.

Give it a Try !!!